# syncing 500GB of data from one GCP bucket to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, synchronization, rsync, bucket

I am trying to sync 500GB of data from one bucket to another across project. Using below command I am able to initiate the sync and it is copying files. But it is taking way long(in 2 days copied 50GB). Is there a faster way around it.
Note: I have nested folders in source bucket and file count is around 74 Million.

gsutil -m rsync -r gs://source_bucket gs://destination_bucket

Comment: The best solution depends on details of what needs to be copied, where the data is located (source and destination), etc. For example, a lot of small files will be much slower than a few large files. Initiating the copy from an instance close to the source will improve performance. You stated 74 million objects. At ten objects per second, a copy will take 85 days. No matter what solution you select (gsutil, Data Transfer Utility), your copy will take a long time. You mentioned 50 GB in two days. Count how many objects were copied. That will give you a rough idea of how long.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following tool[image]

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service?_ga=2.194289709.-1822465630.1624897211&_gac=1.90649320.1659551932.Cj0KCQjwuaiXBhCCARIsAKZLt3k1M43DZD-LBVDZfAetvR5YmX3U6kOWFBJDpHj_LpDjA5UET7O77OgaAricEALw_wcB)

Answer (score 0):

It's more on the step 4 that the interesting happens
[image]